# C - 2D array; all values assign as last value given

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to do FrequencyTable of given parameters.

Full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    double newTable[argc*1][0];
    int newTableCounter = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    double min = 999999999.9;
    double max = -9999999999999999.9;
    int tableLength = argc;
    double temp = 0.0;
    int counter2 = 0;
    int isListed = 0;

    counter = 1;
    /* Min & Max */
    while (counter != tableLength) {
        temp = atof(argv[counter]);
        if (temp > max) {
            max = temp;
        }
        if (temp < min) {
            min = temp;
        }
        counter++;
    }
    printf("Pienin arvo: %f\n", min);
    printf("Suurin arvo: %f\n", max);

  /* FrequencyTabeling */
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
    temp = atof(argv[i]);
    isListed = 0;
        if (newTableCounter == 0) {
            newTable[newTableCounter][0] = temp;
            newTableCounter++;
            isListed = 1;
        }
        else {
          for (int i2 = 0; i2 <= newTableCounter; i2++) {        
        if (temp == newTable[i2][0]) {
          newTable[i2][1]++;
          isListed = 1;
          break;
        }       
          }
        }
        if (isListed == 0) {
      printf(" In newTable addition\n");
      printf(" newTableCounter: %d\n", newTableCounter);
          newTable[newTableCounter][0] = temp;
          newTableCounter++;
        } 
    printf("isListed = %d \n", isListed);
    printf("Temp = %f", temp);
  }
  /* FrequencyTable Print */
  for (int i = 0; i < newTableCounter; i++) {
    printf("%d, %f\n", i, newTable[i][0]);
  }
    return 0;
}
```

However, the table's first dimension defaults as last value given;
When run as "a 1 2 3", every value would be 3.

I'm kind of new to C, just done few years of Java+Python before, so pardon my probably very - beginner problem here.

Comment: `double newTable[argc*1][0]`... what do you think that `[0]` is doing?

Comment: During your years of Java+Python, especially the latter, surely you learnt the importance of indenting code properly!

Comment: Formatting the array as two dimensional with the second dimension being one deep?

Comment: Why do you think that (A) a 1-element array makes sense/is needed and (B) 0 is the size to pass to get 1 element?

Comment: @underscore_d A) Amount of frequency only needs one value per value it's tied to, therefore depth of 1. B) Apparently it'sr not, I somehow thought it'd go like the indexing of arrays. 
C) There was some intendation, which got lost in logistics.

Comment: `double newTable[argc*1][0];`  ... just when you think you've seen everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
double newTable[argc*1][0];
```

you create an array of exactly `argc` elements (the multiplication with `1` is irrelevant), each element is in turn another array of ***zero*** elements of type `double`.

Having an array of zero elements makes no sense, and isn't really allowed by the C standard. If your compiler allows it as an extension, then all indexing into such an array will be *out of bounds* and will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Remember that the value used to declare an array is the *size* (number of elements) and not the top-index. So to create an array of one element (which makes no sense) use the value `1`, as in

```
double newTable[argc][1];
```

In this case the second "dimension" can be skipped, and you would have

```
double newTable[argc];
```

Comment: That UB then means anything can happen, including what you reported in your OP, or nothing, or something catastrophic, or anything in between. In practice, whatever happens is usually a function of your compiler assuming you didn't invoke UB and continuing as though it has valid input, reading wrong parts of memory, etc. The precise details of why UB makes some specific thing happen on some specific day are uninteresting, but you can check the assembly. The language is made to be fast and assumes you're writing valid code, instead of slowing itself down to stop you shooting your own foot off!

Comment: Yes, the problem was the table being formatted with 0-value (instead of 1). 

The argc*1 hack was done in order to circumvent a standard I had to work with.